# How to set max period on image in cache and clear expired items manually using Kingfisher(or AlamofireImage)?

Tags: ios, swift, caching, alamofire, kingfisher

I would like to use multiple cache scenarios for multiple groups like:
1-this image group should exist refresh every 60 seconds.
2-this image group should exist forever unless memory warning occurs.
I don't know how to implement multiple cache programs with one library like AlamofireImage(or Kingfisher). I wrote this code but it can not clear expired images in folder(I dont want to purge all the cache folder content):

```
let downloader = ImageDownloader(name: "shortlived_image_downloader")
let cache = ImageCache(name: "shortlived_cache")
cache.maxCachePeriodInSecond = 60
cell.onPlayingImageView.kf.setImage(with: url,
                                                  placeholder: UIImage(named:"Placeholder_S"),
                                                  options: [.transition(ImageTransition.fade(0.25)),
                                                            .downloader(downloader),
                                                            .targetCache(cache)],
                                                  progressBlock: nil,
                                                  completionHandler: nil)

func clearKFShortLiveCache() {
         let cache = ImageCache(name: "shortlived_cache")
         cache.clearMemoryCache()
         cache.cleanExpiredDiskCache()}
```

Answer (score 1):

In **Kingfisher**,

You can clear different types of `cache` using:

```
let cache = ImageCache(name: "shortlived_cache")

cache.clearMemoryCache()
cache.clearDiskCache()
```

To set `cache size and time` according to your requirement, you can use:

```
cache.maxMemoryCost = YOUR_VALUE
cache.maxCachePeriodInSecond = YOUR_VALUE
cache.maxDiskCacheSize = YOUR_VALUE
```

Image group should exist forever unless memory warning occurs: It is handled automatically by `Kingfisher`.

`AutoPurgingImageCache` concept is not handled by `Kingfisher`. This is supported by `AlamofireImage`. In `Kingfisher`, you have to handle `auto purging` based on `last access date` yourself.

For details on these properties and methods, you can refer to:

https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki/Cheat-Sheet
http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Kingfisher/1.1.2/Classes/ImageCache.html